# Will a Canon GP-E2 GPS Receiver will work with a Canon T3 / EOS 1100D?

Tags: canon, gps, canon-1100d

I own a Canon T3 / EOS 1100D.  I see that a GP-E2 GPS Receiver works with a T4i but I was was wondering if anyone knows if it will work with a T3 and why or why not?  Does the T4i have a certain feature that the T3 does not that would make it work with one but not the other?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it will work, but with quite limited functionality.

Basically it is a manual process with the Canon T3. The GP-E2 will capture logging information, but you have to sync the two up on a computer later.

The T4i has firmware that supports the usage of this GPS logger, your T3 does not as far as I can tell. It might be worth looking at any new T3 firmware updates to see if they perhaps have added this functionality since the release of the GP-E2.

This is the compatibility info from the Canon website:

> Compatible Cameras
>
> - Automatic geotagging when shooting supported by EOS-1D X and later cameras (EOS 5D Mark III and EOS 7D: supported with a firmware update)
> - Manual geotagging after shooting (from logging information) supported by all EOS DIGITAL cameras

Comment: If you are willing to do the sync on your computer, there are much less expensive choices. I have a AGL3080: Amod AGL3080 GPS Data Logger and it works great for geo-tagging shots from my Canon 50D.